# difference between Tedious and sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, tedious

i am new in Backend, i started learning node, i found the ORM sequelize and it's a good to handle with database but also find tedious . i did not understand the relation between them , can i use sequelize only in my project without tedious  ? i found lot of people work with the two but i did not understqand why , i mean if we can use sequelize and interact with db why we have to use tedious at the same time ?

```
      var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

  var config = {
    server: "192.168.1.210",
    options: {},
    authentication: {
      type: "default",
      options: {  
        userName: "test",
        password: "test",
      }
    }
  };

  var connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    }
    // If no error, then good to go...
    executeStatement();
  });



const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

module.exports = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'password', {
    host: '',
    dialect: 'mssql',
  
    pool: {
      max: 50,
      min: 2,
      idle: 10000
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can work with only `sequelize`. As I can see in the documentation.

`Tedious` is a pure-Javascript implementation of the `TDS` protocol, which is used to interact with instances of `Microsoft's SQL Server`. It is intended to be a fairly slim implementation of the protocol, with not too much additional functionality.

But `sequelize` will work with all `db`.

`Sequelize` is a promise-based Node.js ORM for `Postgres`, `MySQL`, `MariaDB`, `SQLite` and `Microsoft SQL Server`. It features solid transaction support, relations, eager and lazy loading, read replication and more.